# django-categories - cannot add parent category

Tags: mezzanine

I've just installed django-categories to my Mezzanine CMS and I cannot use it. Here is description:

- installation: pip install django-categories >> added "categories" and categories.editor in settings.py >> python manage.py syncdb >> python manage.py migrate
- I go to the admin page  and select the Categories from the left menu (url: http://localhost:8000/admin/categories/ ) => as this is first run, there are no categories => I click "+Add" => give a name for the new category => click SAVE and I get the following error:

  Traceback:
  File "/home/user1/.envs/bs-3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response

  112. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
       File "/home/user1/.envs/bs-3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  113. return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
       File "/home/user1/.envs/bs-3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  114. response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
       File "/home/user1/.envs/bs-3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  115. response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
       File "/home/user1/.envs/bs-3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  116. return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
       File "/home/user1/.envs/bs-3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  117. return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
       File "/home/user1/.envs/bs-3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  118. response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
       File "/home/user1/.envs/bs-3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  119. return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
       File "/home/user1/.envs/bs-3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  120. return func(*args, **kwargs)
       File "/home/user1/.envs/bs-3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  121. if form.is_valid():
       File "/home/user1/.envs/bs-3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  122. return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
       File "/home/user1/.envs/bs-3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  123. self.full_clean()
       File "/home/user1/.envs/bs-3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  124. self._clean_form()
       File "/home/user1/.envs/bs-3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_form
  125. self.cleaned_data = self.clean()
       File "/home/user1/.envs/bs-3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/categories/base.py" in clean
  126. decendant_ids = self.instance.get_descendants().values_list('id', flat=True)
       File "/home/user1/.envs/bs-3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mptt/models.py" in _fn
  127. % {'function': func.**name**, 'class': self.**class**.**name**}

Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/categories/category/add/
Exception Value: Cannot call get_descendants on unsaved Category instances

Any ideas ?

Thank you !

GG

Comment: It worked for me with django-categories==1.6 and Mezzanine==4.2.3. Maybe try with a newer version